# After using `uniquetol` to an array, how can i find back where the entries are in the array?

Tags: matlab, floating-point

```
>> a = [12345678.123456789, 12345678.123456788]
a =
   1.0e+07 *
   1.234567812345679   1.234567812345679
>> unique(a)
ans =
   1.0e+07 *
   1.234567812345679   1.234567812345679
>> uniquetol(a,eps)
ans =
     1.234567812345679e+07
```

So the two numbers are considered the same within the tolerance of `eps`.

However, after obtaining `1.234567812345679e+07`. I want to know which entries in `a` match with `1.234567812345679e+07` within the tolerance of `eps` (which is reasonable after I use `uniquetol` with `eps` as tolerance before.)

But

```
find(abs(a-uniquetol(a,eps))<eps)
ans =
     2
```

even

```
>> find(abs(a-uniquetol(a,eps))<=eps)
ans =
     2
>> find(abs(a-uniquetol(a,eps))<=eps*10)
ans =
     2
```

does not give me two entries.

It is only like

```
>> find(abs(a-uniquetol(a,eps))<=eps*10000000)
ans =
     1     2
```

or

```
>> find(abs(a-uniquetol(a,eps))<=eps(uniquetol(a,eps)))
ans =
     1     2
```

will give me back the first entries. (`find(abs(a-uniquetol(a,eps))<=eps(uniquetol(a,eps)))` does not actually always work for some numbers.)

Why? Because I use `uniquetol(a,eps)` before, not `uniquetol(a,eps*10000000)`. So why `find` has to be set at a higher tolerance than `uniquetol`.

Generally `a` is not of two entries only, so if I set the tolerance of `find` too high or by using `find(abs(a-uniquetol(a,eps))<=eps(uniquetol(a,eps)))` it will double count the original entries in `a`. It is because `uniquetol(a,eps)` actually produces two entries sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two additional outputs you can request from `uniquetol`.  From [the documentation page for it](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uniquetol.html), `[C,IA,IC] = uniquetol(___)` returns index vectors `IA` and `IC`, such that `C = A(IA)` and `A~C(IC)` (or `A(:)~C(IC)` if `A` is a matrix), where `~` means the values are within tolerance of each other.  I think you're essentially looking to use `IC` here.  For example, `IC == 1` gives you a logical mask of which entries of `A` "map" to `C(1)`.